# Getting error resolveBackend is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing one strange error while requiring one of my files like :
`const {resolveBackend} = require('../../../utils/factory');`
and I am getting `TypeError: resolveBackend is not a function`

below is my utils/factory/index.js :

```
const {categoryConfig} = require('../../config/categoryConfig');

const resolveService = (category, subCategory) => {
    const item = categoryConfig.find(item => (item.category === category) && (item.subCategory === subCategory));
    return item.service;
}

const resolveBackend = (category, subCategory) => {
    const item = categoryConfig.find(item => (item.category === category) && (item.subCategory === subCategory));
    return item.backend;
}

module.exports = {
    resolveService,
    resolveBackend
}
```

Please note that when I ctrl+click on the require statement it is taking me to the correct file which means it is able to resolve the utils/factory

Comment: I am not too familiar with this format of exporting nodeJS functions. From my current understanding you would have a line `exports.resolveBackend = resolveBackend;` in your module, and then in your root file you would write `const index = require('../../../utils/factory');` and if you want to call that function you would then have the line `index.resolveBackend(category, subcategory);`.

Comment: I don't believe you can export multiple functions with `module.exports`?

Comment: the code you've presented looks fine - what does console.log(resolveBackend.toString()) just after you require it output?

Comment: @James - both comments are incorrect

Comment: when I do console.log(require('../../../utils/factory')); its giving me empty object whereas same is working fine in other place

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I was having cyclic dependency because of that this was the behavior, after resolving cyclic dependency its working smooth, thank you all for your support